# Can a player add new spells to the spellbooks described in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, wizard

In the descriptions, they each say things like "You can use this book as a spellbook" and "It functions as a spellbook for you", so I expect that spells can be added to them. Am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### This is correct.

The Wizard’s spellbook feature says:

> **Copying a Spell into the Book.** When you find a wizard spell of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a spell level you can prepare and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.

When the *Tasha’s* spellbooks say “It functions as a spellbook for you”, they are referring to the Wizard’s spellbook feature quoted above.

Comment: Might want to note, at least in passing, how the special abilities of the spell-book interact with new spells copied into it.